# error alert box when clicking between 2 links

Tags: jquery

I seem to get the random alert when I am clicking between two links and all that is returned is an alert that reads `error`. There is no javascript error logged in the console. The code being executed each time I move between the links is

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "p",
    errorClass: "s_error_msg",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass("error_element").removeClass(validClass);
        $(element).parent("div").addClass("s_error_row");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass("error_element").addClass(validClass);
        $(element).parent("div").removeClass("s_error_row");
    }
});
$("#login").validate();​
```

What could be causing such an alert to appear and what do I need to fix?

**EDIT**

I came across a similar error while traversing the interwebs but for the life of me can't figure it out. If you keep going back and forth between Login and Register multiple times, it throws an error - https://shoppica2.com/index.php?route=account/login

**EDIT**

I have attached an image of the error. I am not calling Facebook but still get the same error.

[image]

Comment: can you please share the link. As far I can see, the alert is not  getting called from here. It might be some other js file or code

Comment: Tried going back and forth about a dozen times, no alert.

Comment: @Barmar - What browser are you using? I tested it with both the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome and I get the error? I also take it that you were testing Login/Register as it appears under Account?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to enclose your code above within a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Using latest Chrome, I was clicking on Login/Register in the Account sidebar. I see things logged in console: "FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()." and "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:". But I don't see "error".

Comment: @Barmar - Hmmm, odd. I kept clicking on login several times and the followed by register and then again login and that's when I got the error I took a screenshot of.

Comment: @Sparky - When you say the code above, which code exactly?

Comment: The _entire_ block of code as you have posted above.  (It certainly won't hurt anything.)

Comment: @Sparky - Sorry am new to jQuery. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Put `$(document).ready(function(){` _before_ your first line, and `});` _after_ your last line, of the code in question.  That's how you'd surround your code with a `document.ready` function.  You've already done something similar in the `head` of your page, so you must already know this.

Comment: @Sparky - Thanks Sparky. I thought that would be the case but wanted to be certain. I did that on an internal version of the site and it still gives me the same error prompt.

Comment: Also, it would be best for you to create a version of this page stripped down to only the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem.  The less we have to dig through, the easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Regarding your problem description about, _"...the code being executed each time I move between the links is..."_, is totally incorrect.  You are reloading the _whole_ page every time you click the links... so ***all*** of the code in the entire page is being re-executed each time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Safari, I finally saw the alert box which only contains the word, `"error"`.  I can say with 100% certainty, that the `.validate()` plugin has absolutely nothing to do with this.  The jQuery Validate plugin does not trigger `alert` boxes.

Have you noticed that the word `"error"` appears five times in [this Facebook code](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js)?  Also, you are getting a JavaScript error, `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().` in the console triggered directly from this Facebook code.  Just remove all traces of the Facebook code to see if the problem clears up.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Sparky. I did remove the Facebook code from a copy of the internal site however the error still occurs.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, Like I stated before,  it would be best for you to create a version of this page stripped down to only the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem. The less we have to dig through, the easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Is there a way I can trap the error when it is produced or is there a way to step through the code each time I jump between the pages?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, Each time you click the link, you totally reload the page.  The best way to find this error has been mentioned several times... strip the page down to almost nothing.  Built it back slowly testing thoroughly each step of the way.  When the problem returns, you'll know.  Otherwise, **please** just provide a stripped down page that only contains the code required to reproduce the problem.  Is there a reason why we need to see six miles of CSS when troubleshooting a JS error?  Can't you just remove that whole "schemer" thing for now?